# removing an outer-level element in the output in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb

By default, jaxb serializes this class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyWrapperClass {
    public Existing existing;
    public Long myField;
}
```

into (e.g.):

```
{
    "existing": {
        "id": 42,
        "fieldA": "the answer",
    },
    "myField": 0,
}
```

Is there a way to make the output to be this?

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "fieldA": "the answer",
    "myField": 0,
}
```

(in other words, remove the outer `existing` element)

Note that the `Existing` class **cannot** be changed.
Actually the reason for wrapping is that we want the new field `myField` in the output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this just a short example of a bigger class you need to remove the wrapper from or is this the actual class your dealing with?

Comment: the class is basically what i'm using. does it matter though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the wrapper can be quite difficult because the marshalling and unmarshalling process doesnt know where to look for the properties. Theres a better explanation for this that [@Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan) would know.

However the easiest way I see to do this is just ignore the marshalling of the `existing` object and add its properties to your `MyWrapperClass`

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@XmlRootElement
public class MyWrapperClass {

    @XmlTransient
    public Existing existing;
    public Long myField;


    @XmlElement(name="id")
    public int getExisitingId() {
        return existing.id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="fieldA")
    public String getExistingFieldA() {
        return existing.fieldA;
    }

}
```

If your using fasterxml (`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`) then take a look at [`@JsonIgnore`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) and [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)

Comment: Ok now i see the reason of your comment. The Existing class has many fields and might be updated some time later. Does that mean I am out of luck here?